# Crescimento mês anterior e relacionamento de tabelas

Tags: powerbi, dax

Fala turma!

Estou trabalhando com Power BI, criando uma analise de crescimento da receita da empresa que eu trabalho, criei uma medida que calcula o valor da receita mensal, considerando data de entrada e saida do cliente;

```
crescimento receita = 
VAR maxdate = MAX(dCalendario[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('clientes'[Valor]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('clientes'),
            ('clientes'[Saida] >= maxdate || ISBLANK('clientes'[Saida]))
            && ('clientes'[Entrada] <= maxdate)
    )
    )
```

Gerei uma base fictícia com nome do cliente, data de entrada, de saída e valor pago;

Também criei uma medida que compara a receita de um mês com o mês anterior para saber quantos % aumentou ou diminuiu;

```
% crescimento mrr = 
VAR MaxDate = LASTDATE(dCalendario[Date])
VAR TotalAtual = 
    CALCULATE(
        [crescimento receita],
        FILTER(
            ALL('dCalendario'[Date]),
            'dCalendario'[Date] = MaxDate
        )
    )
VAR TotalMesAnterior = 
    CALCULATE(
        [crescimento receita],
        FILTER(
            ALL('dCalendario'[Date]),
            'dCalendario'[Date] = EOMONTH(MaxDate, -1)
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(TotalMesAnterior),
        BLANK(),
        DIVIDE(TotalAtual - TotalMesAnterior, TotalMesAnterior)
    )
```

Ambas as medidas estão funcionais, o meu problema agora é o seguinte:

Criei uma tabela de filtro de data dinâmico, para que eu consiga selecionar o período em uma lista ao invés de ficar selecionando no calendário, só que, quando eu aplico o filtro de "Ultimos 3 meses", que pega o período entre 01/01/2024 até hoje (no caso 15/03/2024), no gráfico que eu apliquei a medida de calcular a % dos meses, não aparece o mês de janeiro, mas quando eu filtro manualmente selecionando o mesmo período ele aparece, a ideia é que janeiro apareça;

```
Date Filter = 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR _end_of_month = EOMONTH(_today, 0)
VAR _start_of_year = DATE(YEAR(_today), 1, 1)
VAR _start_of_last_year = DATE(YEAR(_today) - 1, 1, 1)
VAR _end_of_last_year = DATE(YEAR(_today) - 1, 12, 31)
VAR _start_of_last_month = EOMONTH(_today, -2) + 1 // Primeiro dia do mês passado
VAR _end_of_last_month = EOMONTH(_today, -1) // Último dia do mês passado
RETURN
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(_today), MONTH(_today), 1), _today),
        "Filter", "Mês Atual",
        "Order", 1
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(_start_of_last_month, _end_of_last_month),
        "Filter", "Mês Passado",
        "Order", 2
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(_end_of_month - 90, _end_of_month),
        "Filter", "Últimos 3 Meses",
        "Order", 3
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(_start_of_year, EOMONTH(_start_of_year, 2)),
        "Filter", "1º Trimestre",
        "Order", 4
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(_today), 4, 1), EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(_today), 4, 1), 2)),
        "Filter", "2º Trimestre",
        "Order", 5
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(_today), 7, 1), EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(_today), 7, 1), 2)),
        "Filter", "3º Trimestre",
        "Order", 6
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(_today), 10, 1), EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(_today), 10, 1), 2)),
        "Filter", "4º Trimestre",
        "Order", 7
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(_today), 1, 1), _today),
        "Filter", "Ano Atual",
        "Order", 8
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(_start_of_last_year, _end_of_last_year),
        "Filter", "Ano Passado",
        "Order", 9
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(MIN(dCalendario[Date]), MAX(dCalendario[Date])),
        "Filter", "Todo Período",
        "Order", 10
    )
)
```

Essa tabela de date filter está relacionada com uma tabela de datas (dCalendario)

[Print de como está aparecendo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVwh3.png)

Conseguem me ajudar?

Valeu!